# Create woocommerce custom form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a custom form in wordpress woocommerce. I want to create a form to register and sign new customers. could you give me a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain more? What kind of form? Is there a reason you can't use the native woocommerce registeration features? They are easy and work with wordpress login credentials.

Comment: Did my answer help you get where you wanted to go? Or can you be more specific so we can get your woocommerce bigger & better than ever?